# How to add new item to hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I don't know how to add new item to already existing hash. For example, first I construct hash:

```
hash = {item1: 1}
```

After that, I want to add item2, so after this I have hash like this:

```
{item1: 1, item2: 2}
```

I don't know what method to do on hash. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 351, accepted):

Create the hash:

```
hash = {:item1 => 1}
```

Add a new item to it:

```
hash[:item2] = 2
```

Comment: Use [**merge!**](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge!) method `hash.merge!(item2: 2)` to **merge** and save the value **!**

Comment: @maguri `hash.merge!(item2: 2)` performs slower compared to `hash[:item2] = 2` when there is only one argument

Answer (score 82):

If you want to add new items from another hash - use `merge` method:

```
hash = {:item1 => 1}
another_hash = {:item2 => 2, :item3 => 3}
hash.merge(another_hash) # {:item1=>1, :item2=>2, :item3=>3}
```

In your specific case it could be:

```
hash = {:item1 => 1}
hash.merge({:item2 => 2}) # {:item1=>1, :item2=>2}
```

but it's not wise to use it when you should to add just one element more.

Pay attention that `merge` will replace the values with the existing keys:

```
hash = {:item1 => 1}
hash.merge({:item1 => 2}) # {:item1=>2}
```

exactly like `hash[:item1] = 2`

Also you should pay attention that `merge` method (of course) doesn't effect the original value of hash variable - it returns a new merged hash. If you want to replace the value of the hash variable then use `merge!` instead:

```
hash = {:item1 => 1}
hash.merge!({:item2 => 2})
# now hash == {:item1=>1, :item2=>2}
```

Answer (score 48):

**hash.store(key, value)** - Stores a key-value pair in hash.

**Example:**

```
hash   #=> {"a"=>9, "b"=>200, "c"=>4}
hash.store("d", 42) #=> 42
hash   #=> {"a"=>9, "b"=>200, "c"=>4, "d"=>42}
```

<kbd>[Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-store)</kbd>

Comment: This is my preferred way too. It gets me every time is that it's `hash.store("d", 42)` not `hash.store(d: 42)` as I naturally think it is.

Answer (score 28):

It's as simple as:

```
irb(main):001:0> hash = {:item1 => 1}
=> {:item1=>1}
irb(main):002:0> hash[:item2] = 2
=> 2
irb(main):003:0> hash
=> {:item1=>1, :item2=>2}
```

Answer (score 15):

hash[key]=value
Associates the value given by value with the key given by key.

```
hash[:newKey] = "newValue"
```

From Ruby documentation:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm

Answer (score 6):

```
hash_items = {:item => 1}
puts hash_items 
#hash_items will give you {:item => 1}

hash_items.merge!({:item => 2})
puts hash_items 
#hash_items will give you {:item => 1, :item => 2}

hash_items.merge({:item => 2})
puts hash_items 
#hash_items will give you {:item => 1, :item => 2}, but the original variable will be the same old one.
```

Answer (score -3):

Create hash as:

```
h = Hash.new
=> {}
```

Now insert into hash as:

```
h = Hash["one" => 1]
```

Comment: If you try inserting multiple keys this way, you'll see that you're actually creating a new hash each time. Probably not what you want. And if that _is_ what you want, you don't need the `Hash.new` part regardless, because `Hash[]` is already creating a new hash.